# '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, load, filereader

when I do training, there is error at code:

```
with open(f_hr, 'rb') as _f: hr = np.load((_f)[0]['image'], allow_pickle=True)
Typeerror: '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable
```

python 3.7 (google colab)
numpy 1.19.5

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in `(_f)[0]['image']` as `_f` is a object from type `_io.BufferedReader` you can not get anything from the object with the `[]`-operator.

numpy itself expects a file-like object, string, or pathlib.Path in the load function. see [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)

I am not exactly sure, what you are trying to achieve with `(_f)[0]['image']`, but you can find examples on how to work with files [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)

I hope this helps you understand, the problem.